# how to put image in header laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel

I want to put image as header's background and I tried this and it doesn't work.

```css
.header-fit {
  background-image: url('{{ asset('img/justice.jpg') }}');
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header id="home" class="header-fit">
  <div id="maincontent" class="container" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="@">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this css would be worked solution for you if path to image is correct

```
.header-fit {
    background-image: url(img/justice.jpg);
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Here is](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) you would read some info regarding usage of `background-image` property